# Dynamic url generation using Struts 2 using version [struts2-core-2.0.11.1]

Tags: dynamic, struts2

We have a struts2 application in which we need dynamic URL for every individual user. For example John and Eliza are two different users of an application. Here is what we needed:
Actual URL of application -  http://localhost:8080/admin.action
What we want is the following thing when user John or Eliza logins:
For John  – http://localhost:8080/adminjhajkfhjkehp87jhp7i.action
For Eliza – http://localhost:8080/adminiyihhgjgirtuighiu6879ukjt.action
This way every user will have their unique URL and it could help us for catering security needs. can Any body suggest me

Comment: @RomanC this is not duplicate because it uses different version of struts2 in which Wildcard is not supported.

Comment: @MehmoodMemon No, wildcard isn't used.

Comment: @RomanC The solution is achieved using urlrewritefilter-4.0.3.jar in struts2-core-2.3.16 and working perfectly.. The same API isn't working for struts2-core-2.0.11.1.jar. What might be the solution to tackle this problem ?